# wanted to install 2 socket server with LTS, what will be the process to get latest version with LTS?

Tags: lts, gpu, xserver, sockets

my customer is buying dell XW8545 with 2 AMD processors, and asked us to install ubuntu latest version with LTS. please guide...

Comment: Step 1: [Download ISO](https://ubuntu.com/#download) / Step 2: [Create Installation USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) / Step 3: [Install Operating System](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) / Step 4: Profit? 

Comment: Your question is rather unclear; in tags said you want to install Ubuntu Desktop (ie. with `xserver` & thus a GUI on Xorg) but mentioned server in the title?  (servers may not meet the minimum requirements of a desktop system not meeting the GPU requirements for GNOME & Ubuntu desktop; refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).